# Confusing [01459] in awk, what does it mean?

Tags: hadoop, awk

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for year in all/*
do
    echo -ne `basename $year .gz`"\t"
    gunzip -c $year | \
    awk '{ temp = substr($0, 88, 5) + 0;
          quality = substr($0, 93, 1);
          if (temp !=9999 && quality ~ /[01459]/ && temp > max) max = temp }
        END { print max }'
done
```

I'm following the excercise in Hadoop-The Definite Guide 4th Edition. I have had done the first excercise, and it works, but I didn't understand the meaning of *quality ~ /[01459]/*.

Comment: Aside from your question, that script has several issues including deprecated use of backticks, unquoted shell variables, spurious use of semicolons, incorrect `max` calculation, and unnecessary math operations so if you got that from a book I'd treat the rest of the book with a large pinch of salt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html

> exp ~ /regexp/
>
> This is true if the expression exp (taken as a string) is matched by regexp.

and

> [...]
>
> This is called a character list. It matches any one of the characters that are enclosed in the square brackets.

Thus `quality ~ /[01459]/` is `true` if `quality` contains any of `1`, `4`, `5`, `9`

Answer (score 2):

It's a regular expression match, using a [bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

It is true if quality matches any of those characters.

Answer (score 1):

> This is called a character list. It matches any one of the characters that are enclosed in the square brackets.  For example:
>
> `[014]`
>
> matches any one of the characters '0', '1', or '4' in a string.

Mostly taken from: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html